# Too many markers: how to render them server-sided as a tile layer?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm developing a web-app for public transportation info using Google Maps JavaScript API V.3 as front-end. **But due to high number of markers (transit stations) displayed on the maps, the client-side performance is quite poor**, especially map panning (despite markers being dynamically loaded based on map boundary).

For usability design, clustering markers is not an option. So I am considering **rendering these markers as a separate tile layer on server-side**. Then maybe using google maps event onclick and onmousemove on map object to imitate marker interaction.

The question is: *what is a good approach to do this?* Which service/API/software/server should I look into that can accomplish this with minimal overhead and learning curve? Could you please point me to the starting point?

I have checked out Google's Fusion Table, but it doesn't allowed custom marker image, therefor not an acceptable alternative.

My project environment is: PHP CodeIgniter on Apache server as  back-end, PostgreSQL 9.2 + PostGis 2.0 as database system, all hosted on an Amazon EC2 small instance server.

PS. My website is at [www.bussup.com](http://www.bussup.com) , in case you're interested (it's yet to be internationalized so sorry for no English support)

Comment: The KMLLayer is the thing I was looking for, since the icon is customizable, support click event, and can be exported directly from PostGIS by ST_AsKML(). Should be very easy to implements. Thanks Chad Killingsworth for the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use either:

- [Fusion tables](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables)
- [KML Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers)

Both automatically handle this.

Comment: Current Fusion Tables API doesn't yet allow custom external marker image, dommage.

I will checkout the KML layer to see if it can be integrated with my PostGIS database. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Kml Layers do allow a custom icon. You typically use server side scripting to output the kml dynamically. However if dynamically generating the kml is too slow, Google's servers won't display the layer at all.